# Ajax crashes IE 7

Tags: ajax, crash, internet-explorer-7

this is my ajax code

```
function sendAjax(send_data,id)
{
    var ajaxobj;

    alert("After this alert problem occurs!");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) ajaxobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else ajaxobj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    ajaxobj.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if(ajaxobj.readyState==4) 
      {
          if(ajaxobj.responseText.match("confirmPage") != null) document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ajaxobj.responseText;
          else  
          {
            if(id == "FreshContent") 
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<a id=\"refreshpage\" onClick=\"siteSelection('select')\">Failed.Click here to Reload!</a>";
            else
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<a id=\"refreshpage\" onClick=\"sendAjax(0,'latest_gossip_marquee');\">Failed.Click here to Reload!</a>";
          }

          }
      else document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="Loading...."; 
    }

    if(id == "FreshContent") ajaxobj.open("GET","sitexyz.php?"+send_data,true);
    else ajaxobj.open("GET","html/xyz.html",true); 
    ajaxobj.send();     
}
```

Here the FreshContent is a div tag id.it works in opera & firefox but it crashes in my IE7.
to see if the page returned by the server is valid the code checks if the returned page has confirmPage string in it.

Comment: have you considered using a library for this rather than writing your own ajax function? jQuery is the obvious one to suggest, but there's plenty of choice, so no need to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function out - it's a [little more robust](http://bulletproofajax.com/code/) than what you're using.

```
function getHTTPObject() {
  var xhr = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
      xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
      try {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch(e) {
        xhr = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xhr;
}
```